# Compare two csv entries in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm just learning powershell, but have run up on this error that has me stumped. The objective is to take a csv file and ascertain how many groups there are in the file. There will be multiple entries under each group. The end result would be to split the file into different arrays/dictionaries/whathaveyou (i started with powershell 3hrs ago..) based on the groups, keeping the TaxonIDs intact, then export those to separate files. But for now, I'm just at the comparison step.

My practice data look like

```
Group,TaxonID  
AA,1  
AA,2  
BB,3  
BB,4
```

and true data look like:

```
Group,TaxonID
Bilateria_Ropsin,Mus_musculus_Rhabdomeric_MEL  
Bilateria_Ropsin,ROp_OG3TodaroP
```

To do this, I tried to compare the group in one row with the group in the next row. if they differ, then I add one to a variable for later use. Here's what i've got to do the comparison:

```
Set-Variable -name book -value C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Book1.csv
$work = Import-Csv $book
$numgroups = 0
$i=0
foreach ($Group in $work) {
    $Ogroup = $work[$i] | select-object{$_.Group}
    $nextGroup = $work[$i+1] | select-object{$_.Group}
    $compare = $Ogroup.Equals($nextGroup)
    $compare
    $i++
}
```

When i print out $Ogroup and $nextGroup, they give me the proper pairs (AA AA, AA BB, BB BB), but $compare always prints out false. Using Compare-Object gives me an error about $nextGroup being null..so I opted for using .Equals(). CompareTo() throws an error about it not being a valid method.

I'm stumped and need help.

Comment: Will you know ahead of time how many groups there will be?

Comment: unfortunately not, I was just working on the comparison for now. Once that's done I can tie the variable $numgroups into dynamically creating the number of groups I need...that's the plan anyway

Comment: I'm sure I can help, but I feel like in the grand scheme of things we're looking at an exercise in futility with this when you take your entire project into account. Why compare when PowerShell can just split things into groups for you?

Comment: Sounds great! I'm just learning, so I'm sure my methods are not the best. The grouping of Taxa is not intuitive from their values, and duplicate entries (i.e. the same taxon in multiple groups) are allowed. I'll edit the OP so you can see what an actual example would look like. perhaps that would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing isn't needed. Split the groups out first:

```
$book = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Book1.csv"
$work = Import-CSV $book
$Groups = $work | Group-Object Group
ForEach($Group in $Groups){
    "Group Name: "+$Group.name
    "Taxon IDs: "
    $Group.group.TaxonID
}
```

If you want to save each group to a file, within that ForEach loop you can do $Group|export-csv "c:\path\$($Group.name).csv" -notypeinfo

**Edit:** Sorry, was working on an answer when security called me over the intercom and said a water main burst under my truck and they needed me to go move my vehicle. Figured not losing my vehicle to a sinkhole was more important than this.

Comment: Thanks a ton, however this doesn's seem to actually output the groupnames like i thikn you werer going for with 
"Group Name: "+$Group.name. 
wish i could upvote (need more rep).

Comment: Need to capitalize the "n" in $Groups.Name - otherwise works perfectly! I'm trying to modify the loop from below to just print out the taxon id's but can't figure out how to reference them without getting @{Group:xx, TaxonID:xx}.

Comment: You really don't need his loop to get the TaxonIDs. Mine gives you those (edited it to fix that, it should list the IDs properly now). Also, you shouldn't need to capitalize the N in name. I ran that ForEach loop exactly as it is and it ran fine. Hm, maybe version difference?

Comment: Nope, my was my mistake. It should have been ForEach($Group in $Groups) but I had ForEach($Group in $Groups.Name) and that was throwing it all off.

Comment: Bingo! thanks so much. If you don't mind explaining, how does the ($Group in $Groups) work? I hadn't previously defined a $Group variable..

Comment: Sure, ForEach($Variable in $Array) take an array of objects (in this case an array of groupings created by piping $work to Group). For each record in the array if assigns that record to the variable $Group, and processes the scriptblock. Then it moves to the next record, assigns that to $Group, and runs the scriptblock again.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use `Group-Object` CmdLet

```
Set-Variable -name book -value C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Book1.csv
$work = Import-Csv $book

$groups = $work | Group-Object -Property Group
$groups.count
$groups[0].name
$groups[0].Group[0]
for ($i=0 ; $i -lt $groups.count ; $i++) { $groups[$i].name}

for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $groups.count ; $i++)
{ 
  $groups[$i].name;
  for ($j=0 ; $j -lt $groups[$i].count;$j++)
  {
    $groups[$i].group[$j]
  }
}
```

Comment: This certainly helps! but I don't know how to extract
1) the number of groups
2) the taxonID's

Comment: You can use a for loop.